# Accessing Browser Certificate Using Forge

Tags: javascript, security, pki

We are working on a secure application which is using PKI. As a part of requirement we need to build a browser and platform independent application which supports all kind of certificates in browser and on eTokens. We use these certificates for encryption and decryption purpose. All the PKI related work should happen on the client side.

I have found out a javascript library called Forge
https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge/downloads.

What would be the code to
a) get the list of certificates from browser using forge and access 
b) get the public information of the certificate
c) get the private key to encrypt the data

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there's no JS API for accessing certificates in the browser. You can usually export them to PKCS#12 (p12) files, which Forge can read. Keep in mind that users will absolutely not want the server to have access to their private keys (which can also be exported to a PKCS#12 container).

If you really need to have access to private keys in JS and you don't have access to the WebCrypto API (most browsers do not yet as it is incomplete), you'll have to operate with reduced security. Namely, the server will be able to access a user's private key -- which they should be made aware of. New key pairs should be generated for this purpose; existing ones that the user may use elsewhere should not be reused. In the future, JS should have access to cryptographic functions that use private keys -- without exposing the key material to the browser (protecting it from the server). Until then, the only option, if you must use JS, is for the user to trust the server at some level. Forge can be used to generate key pairs, create certificates, and create p12s, etc.

Comment: Hi, after 5 years, it seems there's not yet a way to decrypt a string using the private key of a client certificate in a browser... isn't it?